# Design pattern for building a reasonably complex PHP web service

Tags: php, web-services, api, design-patterns, frameworks

I have just "finished" coding up a relatively involved web service in PHP.  The code base is now a bit of a mess due to last minute requests, changes, add-ons, the usual.

I tried to code it as lightly as possible and in a manner that would maximise performance.

Therefore, I didn't use any frameworks like Zend or any ORMs like Doctrine.

I was wondering if there are any frameworks or design patterns that exist for the sole purpose of building APIs/web services in PHP?

I'm thinking of a refactor and I want to make sure now I know exactly what's involved I can build this thing properly.

Comment: Good question, I think the mark of a really good lightweight framework would be that it would be just as well suited to APIs/web services as it would to web front-end.

Comment: Check out FRAPI - http://getfrapi.com/ It's built by the company echolibre.. who happens to include some of the PEAR leadership.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I apologize in advance for the self-reference here to my own framework - there's no way for me to help you otherwise since I don't use anything else.  I'm not advertising, since it's not public.

As I said in my comment, I think a good web front-end framework shouldn't mean it is a poor web service framework.

Because I was unsatisfied with the restrictive way any of the popular PHP frameworks (CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Kohana) processed requests, as well as their size, I wrote a framework that is designed for really only two purposes, **process a request and determine an action to take**, and then **separate the code for that action from the view (response)**.

The design pattern I use is this:

1. All URLs are rewritten (mod_rewrite) and passed to your execution entry point.
2. Your entry point sets up paths that it will recognize and process. I.E. for a web service:

   - `/users` - User list
   - `/user/*` - User identified by the value where `*` is.
   - `/user/*/delete` - Delete the user
   - `/posts` - List posts
   - `/post/*` - View post `*`
3. Along with the path you specify a function, I.E. `UserActions::saveUser` to be executed *if the HTTP method is `POST`*. The reason it's only executed on POST is to enable output and input to have the same URL.
4. The path also specifies a **view**.  This is the response body that will be sent to the browser.  It can be rendered as straight PHP, or you could plug in a template engine.  In the case of web services, all paths would probably use a single view that renders your data in the output format (JSON, XML, whatever). The view can be just a PHP method and is not required to specify a template file.
5. In the case of a web front-end, the view can have a parent view which wraps it (creating the page from the inside-out).
6. The last point is security.  You can define a security type to be applied to any path.  A security type just specifies what function (like `SecurityManager::authorize`) to check for authorization and if `false` is returned, it redirects to a path of your choosing.

The reasons I believe this design pattern works well for Web Services:

- Enables you to use a single-entry point, but can be used with multiple entry points (for optimization, if needed).
- No assuming that you want your URLs to match your Object Model, like most of the major frameworks do (a notable exception being Zend, as mentioned in the comments).
- Easily adapted to REST (instead of just checking for `POST`, check for other methods too).
- The removal of any HTML feels completely natural, since in this pattern the response is completely separated from processing.
- This can all be done in a few classes.

Comment: I wrote my own framework that does exactly this for the very reasons you listed.

Comment: As did I. If you separate Model and View from Controller, a framework needs no overhead. The 'popular' frameworks don't do that.

Comment: *No assuming that you want your URLs to match your Object Model, like all the major frameworks do.* - Zend Framework doesn't do that, you can route any path to any controller as you see fit, it's probably the most flexible (even if it might be a bit bloated) PHP framework out there.

Comment: @wimvds Thanks, I'm unfamiliar with Zend but I will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, every MVC-based "thing" can really help you.

If you really do not want to use anything (give a try to [CakePHP!](http://cakephp.org)) already existing, strucutring your code following mvc can really help you to split the logic of your application on more layer, and keep it more readable and debuggable.

Of course, also with the better pattern you can write awful code, it's up to you!

Comment: Since I'm writing an API, the MVC design pattern is not really applicable since there aren't really any 'actions' for the controller, and no 'views'.

Comment: I was thinking it while writing the answer, but it strictly depends on how you're writing the api... If the api are somehow RESTFul, a mvc patter is applicable... That's the reason of my answer, but I see that does not fits all the situations!

Comment: @Evernoob: 'view' in your case is whatever you send back to client. 'action' is whatever your service is asked to do by request.

Comment: @Evernoob: A REST API subscribes almost perfectly to an MVC pattern. Also, CakePHP is s-l-o-w.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same patterns you use by simple web applications. A restful service has different interface than a web application, but everything under that interface is the same. You can transform a restful service to a web application like so:

```
METHOD host/resource/data => host/resource/METHOD?data
```

resource is the controller, METHOD is the action.
For example:

```
GET http://library.com/books/123 => http://library.com/books/get?123
```

So you can use front controller and MVC.

Comment: How about actions/methods like "deactivate" or "children"?

Answer (score -1):

A quick Google and I see

- [Frapi](http://getfrapi.com/)
- [Cake](http://api.cakephp.org/)
- [Meditation](http://blog.jonnay.net/archives/584-Meditation-The-PHP-REST-API-Framework..html)
- [Code Canyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/api-framework/140978)

I have never used any of these

Comment: Everyone can google. What is your point?

Comment: @sanmai from my experience at school... thats not true at all.